# MacPorts installs all ports during installation, resulting in a lengthy installation

Tags: macos, macports, package-management

What I did:

I initiated the installation of MacPorts on macOS Monterey and waited for some time.

Then, the installer displayed the message: "Installer:PHRASE:Running package scripts..."

Afterwards, I decided to check the installer's system logs (/private/var/logs/installer.log) and came across the following entries:

```
2023-07-03 06:20:47-07 Virtual-Machine installer[924]: ./postinstall: Adding subport py39-re2 

2023-07-03 06:20:47-07 Virtual-Machine installer[924]: ./postinstall: Adding subport py310-re2
```

There are several thousand such lines (but with other ports). I also tried on other virtual machines with different versions of macOS, and the issue occurred on macOS Monterey & macOS Big Sur, but not on macOS Ventura.

How can I resolve this problem, and what could be the cause?

Comment: MacPorts did not install Python 3.9 and 3.10 just because you ran the package download.  Further, Python 3.11 is the default in MacPorts.  What else did you install?

Comment: In my cases, macPorts is part of another installer. Detecting my postinstall output of the latest version of macPorts and compiling it with a .pkg file via installer command.

Comment: It's your deployment, but I'd have to say that I think installing MacPorts under the hood is a bad idea.